# Java day counter for discounts

Tags: java

I am programming a card that allows you to pay bus tickets,it has a special discount for "Students"(80% off) in the first two tickets you pay in the day. 
I placed a variable that counts the amount of times you travel and then it discounts according if you haven't exceeded  the 2 discounts that you are granted, but i cant find i way to make the variables value back to 0 when a day has passed. I must specify that the code i will pas you is an extension(inheritance) of the object `TravelCard` and there are several variables as `priceXtravel`, and `balance` that where inherited from it.

```
public class StudentTravelCard {
    private double discount;
    private int discountCounter;
    public StudentTravelCard(int cardiD){
        super(cardiD);
        discount = 0.8;
    }
    public void newTravel() {
        if(discountCounter < 2) {
            super.newTravel();
            balance += (priceXtravel*discount);
            discountCounter ++;
        }
        else {
            super.newTravel;
            //discountCounter = 0;?  what if they continue to travel on that day?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: make the variable local then it back to 0 every time.

Comment: if i do that, then he would have unlimited discounts, and the idea is only to have 2 per day @RamisWachtler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your newTravel() you can just remove the commented line and add another method resetDay() to reset the back to 0 discounts in a new day.

Of course resetDay() will have to be called by something that *knows* about the current time, etc.

```
public class StudentTravelCard {
    private double discount;
    private int discountCounter;
    public StudentTravelCard(int cardiD){
        super(cardiD);
        discount = 0.8;
    }
    public void newTravel() {
        if(discountCounter < 2) {
            super.newTravel();
            balance += (priceXtravel*discount);
            discountCounter ++;
        }
        else {
            super.newTravel();
        }
    }

    public void resetDay() {
        discountCounter = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your model, there is no date or time information. If you want to have a behaviour that depends on time ("one day") you will have to store this info in order to compute some *elapsed time* between the first travel and the new one.

The implementation will depend on your requirements:

- the discount apply on 2 travels on the same day from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 ?
- or the discount apply on 24 hours starting from a first travel ?

---

Anyway, the logic is to store a `Date` or `Calendar` instance when there is a first call to `newTravel()`, then compare this date with the current date of following calls.

- If the dates are in the same day

  - if `discountCount < 2`, then apply the discount
  - else apply full price
- else (travel is on a different day as the stored date) reset the stored date with the current date.

And so on...